# django: default for non-nullable field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am learning django by doing some tutorials and am currently on ownership in the [effective-django](http://www.effectivedjango.com/tutorial/authzn.html#checking-ownership) tutorial. Unfortunately, the tutorials is written for an older version of django so some things are slightly different.

I am running into problems when adding an 'owner' field to my model Contact in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Contact(models.Model):
    """
        Interface for contact class
    """
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join([self.first_name, self.last_name])

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('contacts-view', kwargs={'pk': self.id})
```

When trying to run 'makemigrations', i get warnings:

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'owner' to contact without a default: can't do that

This makes sense for an existing database, so i tried flushing the database. However, the problem remains. What should be the default value for the field owner? I also tried making the field nullable but that gives me the error that field owner cannot be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually set to `1`.  In this case already existed records will be assigned to the first user.

If you want you can later reassign these records in the next data migration.

Comment: Adding this indeed solves the problem, does this have any influence on subsequently added contacts?

Comment: No, newly added contacts will not have any default value for this field. This value will be set only to records that are exist in the database at the time of migration.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it does not matter if the database is empty or not. It matters that you probably have already at least one migration that first creates the model, and then you try to run `makemigrations` that adds the field.

If these migrations are not too important for you (which I recon they are not since this is a tutorial), just delete all previous migrations and run `makemigrations` fresh.

Alternatively, you would have to manually change migrations, possibly provide a default value etc.

Comment: ok but when i remove all migrations and reset the database, i still get the warning 'contacts_contact.owner_id may not be null'